# Convert multiple user inputs as mkdir parameter to create multiple folders - Bash script

Tags: bash, input, directory-structure

I want to create multiple folders using the user input. As an example, if the user has written `java,python,react` the result that i'm looking for is having then the folders `java`, `python` and `react` respectively. But what happens, is that a folder with the name `{java,python,react}` is created. The comma is not recognized anymore.

```sh
## The code
read -p "External projects: " EXTERNAL_PROJECTS 

mkdir -p {$EXTERNAL_PROJECTS}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because brace expansion is performed before parameter expansion. That is, after the parameter `EXTERNAL_PROJECTS` is expanded, the resulting string is not rescanned for brace expansion. One way to solve this problem is to use an array:

```
IFS=',' read -r -p "External projects: " -a EXTERNAL_PROJECTS

mkdir -p "${EXTERNAL_PROJECTS[@]}"
```

Comment: Thank you @Nejat . In order to solve my problem, I used a for loop to iterate over the array.

Comment: @bmalbusca Surely, if you have a more complex task for each project, you should use a loop like that; `for project in "${EXTERNAL_PROJECTS[@]}"; do ...; done`. But no loop is needed for a simple `mkdir`. By the way, the `"${EXTERNAL_PROJECTS[*]}"` was wrong in the original answer. Updated now. The correct one is `"${EXTERNAL_PROJECTS[@]}"`